# How do you use VBS to format an existing XLSX file from command prompt?

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to format an existing xlsx file like a table including auto sizing columns and alternating row color using the command prompt.
I know this can be done but I lost the .vbs script I had.
All I can find are scripts like this that do not reference an existing xlsx and are creating them instead.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'Bind to the Excel object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  
'Create a new workbook.
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
  
'Select the first sheet
Sheet = 1
  
'Bind to worksheet.
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet)
  
'Name the worksheet
objSheet.Name = "VBS_Excel_Example"
  
'Set the save location
strExcelPath = "d:\Vbs_Excel_Example.xlsx"
  
'--------------------------------------------------------
'Populate the worksheet with data
'--------------------------------------------------------
'   objSheet.Cells(row, column).Value = "Whatever"
  
'Add some titles to row 1
objSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Name" 'Row 1 Column 1 (A)
objSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Description" 'Row 1 Column 2 (B)
objSheet.Cells(1, 3).Value = "Something Else" 'Row 1 Column 3 (C)
  
'Add some data using a loop
For row = 2 to 10
    objSheet.Cells(row, 1).Value = "Item Name"
    objSheet.Cells(row, 2).Value = "Item Description"
    objSheet.Cells(row, 3).Value = "Item Something Else"
Next
  
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Format the spreadsheet
'--------------------------------------------------------
'Put the first row in bold
objSheet.Range("A1:C1").Font.Bold = True
  
'Change the font size of the first row to 14
objSheet.Range("A1:C1").Font.Size = 14
  
'Freeze the panes
objSheet.Range("A2").Select
objExcel.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
  
'Change column A and B to use a fixed width
objExcel.Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 20
objExcel.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 30
  
'Change column C to autofit
objExcel.Columns(3).AutoFit()
  
'Change the background colour of column A to a light yellow
objExcel.Columns(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
  
'Change the font colour of column C to blue
objExcel.Columns(3).Font.ColorIndex = 5
  
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Save the spreadsheet and close the workbook
'--------------------------------------------------------
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs strExcelPath
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
  
'Quit Excel
objExcel.Application.Quit
  
'Clean Up
Set objSheet = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Do you want it to be *like* a table, or an actual table?

Comment: Just look like a table @BigBen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you bind the object, you need to load the existing file, like this:

```vb
'Bind to the Excel object
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Workbooks.Open ("d:\Vbs_Excel_Example.xlsx")
  
'Select the first sheet
Sheet = 1
  
'Bind to worksheet.
Set objSheet = objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet)

objSheet.Cells(row, column).Value = "Whatever"
```

and then do the rest...

I wasn't sure in which part you were stuck, tell me if more adjustments needed

Comment: How do you select the sheet you want to update? Any chance you could show a full script with just one update parameter?

Comment: You can do it just the same as the code you attached. What exactly is missing?